# Storing and accessing a collection of strings (STD C++)

Tags: c++, string, vector

```
SKU1       SKU2        Description
"01234"    "34545"     "White Bread"
"01545"    "34236"     "Wheat Bread"
```

I need to cross-reference these three fields, i.e. retrieve SKU2 while knowing SKU1, SKU1 while knowing SKU2, and Description while knowing either SKU1 or SKU2.

I'm curious - what is the best way to do this? Vectors using search() or find()? Using a map somehow?

I currently have it working using a `vector< vector<string> >`, looping through the 'parent' vectors and the 'child' vectors, comparing the values, but this seems primitive.

Basically, I need a vector that uses any of its strings as an index to return one of the two other values. Is the general way I'm doing it considered acceptable/optimal?

```
vector< vector<string> > products;

int i = 0;
for( i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    products.push_back( vector<string>() );

    products[i].push_back( "SKU1" );
    products[i].push_back( "SKU2" );
    products[i].push_back( "Description" );

}
```

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Could you use external libraries or you are stuck with the standard library only?

Comment: I could use an external library, but I'd prefer to use STD whenever possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build three `std::map<std::string, std::string>`s: one to map SKU1s to SKU2s, one to map SKU1s to Descriptions, and one to map SKU2s to Descriptions. (Better yet, use std::unordered_map, if you have it (C++0x)).

This is assuming that you have a lot of data and are prioritizing speed rather than memory usage.

Comment: Thanks! How would I retrieve SKU2 from SKU1? Would I need another map going the other way, or is there a way to retrieve a key from a value?

Answer (score 1):

[Boost BiMap.](http://cablemodem.fibertel.com.ar/mcape/oss/projects/mc_projects/boost_projects/boost_bimap.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using two maps that index into an object that has the information you need:

```
struct MyInfo
{
  std::string SKU1;
  std::string SKU2;
  std::string Description;
};

std::map<std::string, MyInfo *> SKU1map;
std::map<std::string, MyInfo *> SKU2map;

MyInfo * newProduct = new MyInfo; ///Do not forget to delete!!
newProduct->SKU1 = //SKU1 value
newProduct->SKU2 = //SKU2 value
newProduct->Description = //Description value

SKU1map[newProduct->SKU1] = newProduct;
SKU2map[newProduct->SKU2] = newProduct;
```

This will be a decently fast implementation(much better than linear search), and if you deal with many product instances, then it will also be more memory efficient.

Comment: Wow. Very interesting idea. I don't suppose there's a way to do something similar without pointers...

Comment: Why would you want to do it without pointers? :)
You can do it by pushing your structs onto a vector for instance, and then just use pointers in your maps to reference them, this way you wont need to manually free them up afterwards, but you'd still use the pointers in the maps otherwise you are going to duplicate the data all over the place.

Comment: @Strahd_za: If you do this, you'll need to pre-set the size of the vector so that the pointers won't be invalidated as you add new items.